# Best practice for displaying multiple views in a single page

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views

I am working on a Drupal 7 website where there are many pages which utilize multiple views.

The way I am doing this right now is by creating a page from Drupal admin panel, and in the edit mode of that page I am calling views_embed_view to display those multiple views.

[image]

Other ways I could do this is by creating a template for that page, and putting my code inside the template.

Yet another way is to use View Fields View (https://drupal.org/project/views_field_view) and embed the second view inside the first one.

**I want to know, performance wise which is the best practice?**

Answer (score 0):

1. Create view for main page, then attach all other views to it.
2. Use panels and add all required views.

For Performance you need to optimized your views and monitor using Devel tool.

Cheers!!!